# ServiceLoader does not locate implementation when Gradle javafxplugin is used

Tags: gradle, javafx, serviceloader

I am implementing a program where the core part is separated from the GUI and loaded at runtime as a service. I am struggling for weeks to have the implementation discovered at runtime. To try isolating the problem, I picked up a minimal ServiceLoader example from here https://reflectoring.io/service-provider-interface and inflated it into my project structure. I got the the conclusion that the `javaxplugin` is messing up something. The plugin is required for the GUI of my project, but is not required to run the code of the ServiceLoader. I am using version 0.0.10 of `org.openjfx.javafxplugin`, the last version is 0.0.13 but this causes the additional problem that the main class cannot be found anymore, so I am staying with the older version for the moment.
If the plugin is not requested in the build.gradle, the ServiceLoader code works, the implementation is loaded and the program gives the expected output. When the javaxplugin is requested in the build.gradle, the program does not work anymore.

Does anybody have a suggestion? I am really stuck because this is a JavaFX application and I need that plugin.

The project is a Gradle project with 3 subprojects (modules): the api, the implementation (core) and the application (GUI). The relevant files are here below.

API module-info.java:

```
module tlapi {
  exports com.chesolver.spi;
  exports com.chesolver;
}
```

The strange thing here is that if I enable the javafx pluging, the compiler rises the error
`com.chesolver.spi.Library: module tlapi does not declare 'uses'`, which appears pretty wierd to me,since module tlapi is the api and `com.chesolver.spi.Library` is part of the interface contained in this module.

API build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'tubesheetlayout.java-library-conventions'
}
```

core module-info:

```
module tlcore {
    requires tlapi;
}
```

core build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'tubesheetlayout.java-library-conventions'
    id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':api')
}
```

application module-info:

```
module tlclient {
    requires tlapi;
}
```

application build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'tubesheetlayout.java-application-conventions'

    // *NOTICE* if uncommented the ServiceLoader code does not work
    //id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.13'
    
    //id 'org.javamodularity.moduleplugin' version '1.8.9'
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':api')
    implementation project(':core')
}

application {
    mainClass = "com.chesolver.library.LibraryClient"
}
```

Comment: I don't see the `uses` and `provides` statements in the module-info classes: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html

Comment: *"I am using version 0.0.10 of org.openjfx.javafxplugin, the last version is 0.0.13 but this causes the additional problem that the main class cannot be found anymore"* -> maybe that is a problem with your usage of the 0.0.13 plugin version rather than the 0.0.13 plugin, perhaps 0.0.10 had bugs which allowed your usage to work.  For a modular application, the class names should be qualified by the module name, e.g. assuming the module name which provides the main class is `tlclient`, then the fully qualified name would be `tlclient/com.chesolver.library.LibraryClient`.

Comment: *"If the plugin is not requested in the build.gradle, the ServiceLoader code works, the implementation is loaded and the program gives the expected output. When the javaxplugin is requested in the build.gradle, the program does not work anymore.*" -> probably in one configuration it is not treating the application as modular (e.g. it is working off the class path), and in the other it is, hence it breaks because the modules are not well defined.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Your main issue (incorrectly specifying service modules) and resources on how to fix it**

For a Java platform modular application, you need to use Java Platform modular service definitions in your modules.  This means using the `provides` and `uses` statements in your `module-info.java`.

Your code, and the [service tutorial you linked](https://reflectoring.io/service-provider-interface), don't integrate services into the Java platform module system. The Maven module system discussed in the tutorial (and probably Gradle modules too), is something completely different.

To learn about modular services, study the "Services" sections in:

- [The State of the Module System](https://openjdk.org/projects/jigsaw/spec/sotms/#services).
- The [Jenkov module tutorial](https://jenkov.com/tutorials/java/modules.html#services) where it explains the `provides` and `uses` statements for `module-info.java`.
- The [`ServiceLoader` javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), which should be thoroughly reviewed and understood.

Baeldung provides [example code](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/tree/master/core-java-modules/core-java-9-jigsaw/src/simple-modules) for a [modular service tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity#6-adding-a-service), which is simpler than what I have in this answer.  But the Baeldung tutorial doesn't demonstrate binding multiple service implementations, jlinking, or using the loaded service modules from a JavaFX application, which is why I added an example for those things here.

**Key Advice**

My suggestion about this is: *don't use the service mechanism unless you know you need it*.

**Example Solution**

I know this question is about Gradle specifically, but I don't really use that tool.  I will provide an alternate solution using Maven.  Some aspects of it will carry directly over to Gradle, and others you will need to adapt.

The solution consists of a multi-module Maven project.  Each of the submodules corresponds to a Java platform module. There is a parent pom.xml to specify all of the child modules and all of the child modules inherit from the parent.

The submodules involved are these:

- *shape-service*: `ShapeFactory` interface that can create shapes.
- *circle-provider*: a `ShapeFactory` implementation that provides circles.
- *square-provider*: a `ShapeFactory` implementation that provides squares.
- *shape-app*: a JavaFX application that loads the available `ShapeFactory` service providers and uses them to generate shapes.

[image: shape provider]

Select the shape factory service provider from the combo box, then click "Create Shape" and the selected provider will be used to generate a shape, which will then be displayed.

I'll post the code here, unfortunately, there is a lot of it :-(

*Building and running in Idea*

You can import the maven project from the root directory into the Idea IDE.  The project will load as a single Idea project, with multiple Idea project modules.  When you run the main `ShapeApplication` class from the IDE, the IDE will automatically build all the modules and provide the services to your application.

*Building and running from the command line*

To build everything, run `mvn clean install` on the root of the project.  To create a jlinked app change to the `shape-app` directory and run `mvn javafx:jlink`.

```
$ tree
.
├── circle-provider
│   ├── circle-provider.iml
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── com
│               │   └── example
│               │       └── shapeservice
│               │           └── circleprovider
│               │               └── CircleProvider.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── pom.xml
├── shape-app
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── shape-app.iml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── com
│               │   └── example
│               │       └── shapeapp
│               │           └── ShapeApplication.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── shape-service
│   ├── pom.xml
│   ├── shape-service.iml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── java
│               ├── com
│               │   └── example
│               │       └── shapeservice
│               │           └── ShapeFactory.java
│               └── module-info.java
├── shapes.iml
└── square-provider
    ├── pom.xml
    ├── square-provider.iml
    └── src
        └── main
            └── java
                ├── com
                │   └── example
                │       └── shapeservice
                │           └── squareprovider
                │               └── SquareProvider.java
                └── module-info.java
```

The `.iml` are just idea module project files, you can ignore them.

Parent *pom.xml*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>shapes</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>shapes</name>

    <modules>
        <module>shape-service</module>
        <module>circle-provider</module>
        <module>square-provider</module>
        <module>shape-app</module>
    </modules>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <javafx.version>19</javafx.version>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>19</source>
                    <target>19</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

*shape-service*

```
module com.example.shapeservice {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    exports com.example.shapeservice;
}
```

---

```
package com.example.shapeservice;

import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

public interface ShapeFactory {
    double PREF_SHAPE_SIZE = 40;

    Shape createShape();
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>shape-service</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>shapes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*circle-provider*

```
module com.example.shapeservice.circleprovider {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires com.example.shapeservice;

    provides com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory
            with com.example.shapeservice.circleprovider.CircleProvider;
}
```

---

```
package com.example.shapeservice.circleprovider;

import com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Circle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class CircleProvider implements ShapeFactory {
    private static final Color[] colors = {
            Color.RED, Color.ORANGE, Color.YELLOW, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.VIOLET
    };

    @Override
    public Shape createShape() {
        return new Circle(
                PREF_SHAPE_SIZE / 2,
                randomColor()
        );
    }

    private static Color randomColor() {
        return colors[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(colors.length)];
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>circle-provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>shapes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>shape-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*square-provider*

```
module com.example.shapeservice.squareprovider {
    requires javafx.graphics;
    requires com.example.shapeservice;

    provides com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory
            with com.example.shapeservice.squareprovider.SquareProvider;
}
```

---

```
package com.example.shapeservice.squareprovider;

import com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;

import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLocalRandom;

public class SquareProvider implements ShapeFactory {
    private static final Color[] colors = {
            Color.CYAN, Color.MAGENTA, Color.YELLOW, Color.BLACK
    };

    @Override
    public Shape createShape() {
        return new Rectangle(
                PREF_SHAPE_SIZE, PREF_SHAPE_SIZE,
                randomColor()
        );
    }

    private static Color randomColor() {
        return colors[ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt(colors.length)];
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>square-provider</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>shapes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>shape-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

*shape-app*

```
module com.example.shapeapp {
    requires javafx.controls;
    requires com.example.shapeservice;

    uses com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory;

    exports com.example.shapeapp;
}
```

---

```
package com.example.shapeapp;

import com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.*;
import javafx.geometry.*;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.scene.layout.*;
import javafx.scene.shape.Shape;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.Comparator;
import java.util.ServiceLoader;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;

import static com.example.shapeservice.ShapeFactory.PREF_SHAPE_SIZE;

public class ShapeApplication extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        ObservableList<ShapeFactory> shapeFactories = loadShapeFactories();
        stage.setScene(new Scene(createUI(shapeFactories)));
        stage.show();
    }

    private ObservableList<ShapeFactory> loadShapeFactories() {
        ServiceLoader<ShapeFactory> loader = ServiceLoader.load(ShapeFactory.class);

        return FXCollections.observableList(
                loader.stream()
                        .map(
                                ServiceLoader.Provider::get
                        ).sorted(
                                Comparator.comparing(
                                        shapeFactory -> shapeFactory.getClass().getSimpleName()
                                )
                        ).collect(
                                Collectors.toList()
                        )
        );
    }

    private Pane createUI(ObservableList<ShapeFactory> shapeFactories) {
        ComboBox<ShapeFactory> shapeCombo = new ComboBox<>(shapeFactories);
        shapeCombo.setButtonCell(new ShapeFactoryCell());
        shapeCombo.setCellFactory(param -> new ShapeFactoryCell());

        StackPane shapeHolder = new StackPane();
        shapeHolder.setPrefSize(PREF_SHAPE_SIZE, PREF_SHAPE_SIZE);

        Button createShape = new Button("Create Shape");
        createShape.setOnAction(e -> {
            ShapeFactory currentShapeFactory = shapeCombo.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();
            Shape newShape = currentShapeFactory.createShape();
            shapeHolder.getChildren().setAll(newShape);
        });
        createShape.disableProperty().bind(
                shapeCombo.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().isNull()
        );

        HBox layout = new HBox(10, shapeCombo, createShape, shapeHolder);
        layout.setPadding(new Insets(10));
        layout.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);
        return layout;
    }

    private static class ShapeFactoryCell extends ListCell<ShapeFactory> {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(ShapeFactory item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item != null && !empty) {
                setText(item.getClass().getSimpleName());
            } else {
                setText(null);
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>shape-app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>shape-app</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>com.example</groupId>
        <artifactId>shapes</artifactId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>shape-service</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>circle-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.example</groupId>
            <artifactId>square-provider</artifactId>
            <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>com.example.shapeapp/com.example.shapeapp.ShapeApplication</mainClass>
                            <launcher>shape-app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>shape-app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>shape-app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                            <bindServices>true</bindServices>
                            <runtimePathOption>MODULEPATH</runtimePathOption>
                            <jlinkVerbose>true</jlinkVerbose>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Caveats**

- Splitting stuff up into modules and services like this makes things more complicated.
- Many small things can go wrong, especially typos from copy and paste if you forget to change names.
- The compiler won't pick up some typos because the service modules are dynamically discovered.
- You can't mix package names across modules.
- Linking with jlink is trickier because you need to ensure the services are on the jlinked module path and that you instruct jlink to bind them.
- The tools are a bit obtuse in the error messages.
- If not properly configured, the modules won't be found and the system will think that there are no matching services available.
- Actually install *all* of your modules into your maven repository before each time you link it, otherwise it may pick up old versions or not find your software (this may not be actually necessary, but seemed the case in my experience).
- Binding services will make your jlink image huge if you just use the default `bind-services` option.  Apparently you can just bind listed services rather than all, but I could not find out how to do that with the javafx-maven-plugin.  You can probably get more fine-grained control using the jlink command line than the maven plugin, though that would be more painful.
- If you don't explicitly put a `MODULEPATH` setting in the javafx-maven-plugin, it won't find your service modules.
- Always check the jlink verbose output to ensure that all of your expected services are being bound.
- When working with a multi-module project like this, I strongly recommended keeping all of your modules at the same version number (centrally configured in the parent pom.xml), otherwise it is quite easy to link to obsolete versions.  That isn't how this example project is setup though.  To pin the version, define a `shape.version` property in the parent pom.xml and, wherever there is `1.0-SNAPSHOT`, replace that with the `${shape-version}`, then all projects will always use the same version.
- The code assumes that everything is operating in a modular environment, with nothing running from the classpath.  If you want to have services that work on the classpath, then you would need to do more work (e.g. to define service metadata in `MANIFEST.MF` files).  I recommend only supporting the 100% modular environment unless you absolutely also have to support classpath execution.
- I am sure there are more subtle and potential issues I haven't mentioned here.

Comment: Thanks jewelsea for you reply, which acutally solves the problem. I was refactoring an existing project: I changed the IDE, introduced the Gradle build tool and modularized the application. I am quite new with Gradle and module system so the project is affected by several overlapping issues. Anyway, for what concerns ServiceLoader non finding the implementation, the key point as you say is the incorrect specification of service modules, the proper way is here [link](https://www.baeldung.com/java-9-modularity#6-adding-a-service)